# The font is not being displayed at the bottom of the container?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code to display font with a background in a small container . .

here is the css

```
.cons_save h4{font:bold 22px/60px Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:20px 0px -15px 20px; color:#f78d1d;vertical-align: bottom; background:url(../images/save_bg_cons.png) no-repeat; width:151px; height:69px;}
```

im not able to put it ! in the bottom of that container whatever the other content above it in the container remains

My HTML CODE

```
<div id ="<?php echo $store->branch_id;?>Collect" style="display:block">    
 <span class="cons_save fl clr">
  <h4><?php echo $save. " %"; ?> </h4>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML code is missing - please provide HTML code (and maybe a little example of your problem online?)

Comment: Where is you HTML? Looks like you forgot to post it.

Comment: Sorry ! here it is . . .

Comment: It is semantically invalid to put block level elements inside inline element (h4 inside span).

Answer (score 1):

First, I would write each property of the CSS separately as follows:

```
.cons_save h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px/60px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px 0px -15px 20px;
    color: #f78d1d;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background: url(../images/save_bg_cons.png) no-repeat;
    width: 151px;
    height: 69px;
    }
```

then, it seems that the class name does not match the one in the span tag.

You should actually try and set the class name in the header tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `heading` tags insides `spans`

```
<div id ="<?php echo $store->branch_id;?>Collect" style="display:block">    
     <div class="cons_save fl clr">
        <h4><?php echo $save. " %"; ?> </h4>
     </div>
</div>
```

And also heading having a lot of margin & padding by default. So might be the reason to come in the bottom. Be sure to clear it

```
.cons_save h4 { margin: 0;padding:0; }
```

It works without the reset too, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7rteq/)

Answer (score 0):

not sure what is the problem, if you could sepcify using http://jsfiddle.net/ then it would be nice.

anyway, i suggest you changing `span` to `div`, like this:

```
<div id ="<?php echo $store->branch_id;?>Collect" style="display:block">    
 <div class="cons_save fl clr">
  <h4><?php echo $save. " %"; ?> </h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

moreover, you have `vertical-align` which would not work, unless you add to your css `display: table-cell` [note: this will not work in IE7]:

```
.cons_save h4{display: table-cell;font:bold 22px/60px Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;margin:20px 0px -15px 20px; color:#f78d1d;vertical-align: bottom; background:url(../images/save_bg_cons.png) no-repeat; width:151px; height:69px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to use that property (`vertical-align`) on block level elements. And don't put a `heading` inside a `span`.
Without changing the HTML I would do this:

```
#Collect{
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  width: 151px;
  height: 69px;
 }

h4{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px/60px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  color: #f78d1d;
  background: url(../images/save_bg_cons.png) no-repeat;
  background:#eee;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}​
```

You can even get rid of the `span`.